# QtWebkit bugs 62316, 61317

Tags: qt, webkit, qtwebkit

I am using Qt 4.8.5 on 32bit win7. I think I am running into bugs 61317, 61316 of webkit.
Look at: https://lists.webkit.org/pipermail/webkit-unassigned/2011-May/329719.html .

Here is my backtrace:

```
0   _NPN_DeallocateObject   QtWebKitd4      0x100a70ce  
1   _NPN_ReleaseObject  QtWebKitd4      0x100a70b7  
2   JSC::Bindings::CInstance::~CInstance    QtWebKitd4      0x1015da2c  
3   JSC::Bindings::CInstance::`vector deleting destructor'  QtWebKitd4      0x1015e7ef  
4   WTF::RefCounted<JSC::Bindings::Instance>::deref QtWebKitd4      0xf97b351   
5   WTF::derefIfNotNull<JSC::Bindings::Instance>    QtWebKitd4      0xfce15f4   
6   WTF::RefPtr<JSC::Bindings::Instance>::~RefPtr<JSC::Bindings::Instance>  QtWebKitd4      0xfe79fa2   
7   JSC::Bindings::RuntimeObject::~RuntimeObject    QtWebKitd4      0x1009c961  
8   JSC::Bindings::CRuntimeObject::~CRuntimeObject  QtWebKitd4      0x102a6ba8  
9   JSC::Bindings::CRuntimeObject::`vector deleting destructor' QtWebKitd4      0x102a6bdf  
10  JSC::MarkedBlock::allocate  QtWebKitd4      0x102efe0f  
11  JSC::MarkedSpace::allocateFromSizeClass QtWebKitd4      0x102ef842  
12  JSC::MarkedSpace::allocate  QtWebKitd4      0xf6f8da4   
13  JSC::Heap::allocate QtWebKitd4      0xf6f8d51   
14  JSC::JSCell::operator new   QtWebKitd4      0xf6f8d25   
15  cti_op_new_regexp   QtWebKitd4      0x10355358  
16  operator delete[]   MSVCR100D       0x52347eee  
17  JSC::JITCode::execute   QtWebKitd4      0x1032c9eb  
18  JSC::Interpreter::execute   QtWebKitd4      0x10329ceb  
19  JSC::evaluate   QtWebKitd4      0x1030917a
```

But problem is I am not allowed to access the bug details at:

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=61317 or

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=61316

I need to know if the bug has been fixed and what version to use to get the fix or else if there is any workaround? Please do provide any info. Thank you.

Best regards,
sky.

Answer (score 0):

I have spent a lot of time before found actual answer. Yeah, they fixed this bug: [link](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=101968) [link](http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/87179).